# Wisdom behind that the Quran begins with bismillah

Tags: quran, allah, uloom-al-quran

Every surah of the Quran begins with *bismillah*, translated as *'In the name of Allah(swt)'*.
Here we see that the name of Allah is not in the beginning. I in my poor knowledge cannot understand why the starting word is something other then the word Allah. Can anyone elaborate on that.

Comment: Why should the word Allah be the beginning?

Comment: Because Allah (swt) is THE awwal.

Comment: HE is also The Akhir so why isn't the last word in the qur'an Allah? This simply isn't a convincing argument. Also be aware that the qur'an isn't even arranged chronologically. At least starting with hamd or in Allahs name seems much more reasonable.

Comment: Yes I am only here to admit my ignorance and am ready to learn Insha Allah :)

Comment: I don't know Arabic too much but what does *Allahuma bismika* mean?

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq - afaik this means "O Allah with your name..."
If you know or understand Urdu or Hindi watch this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZGwn7M2b90

Comment: @Medi1Saif, as gallickgunner said, Allahuma bismika may roughly translate to bismillah and also begins with Allah, so why Bismillah